# Write Pyspark Dataframe to Hive table - name 'database' is not defined Error

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe to a hive table with the following code on Jupyternotebook:

```
df.repartition("dt").write.partitionBy("dt").format("orc").saveAsTable(fraud_nr.test)
```

fraud_nr is the database I am trying to write the table to. But I got this error.

```
> NameError: name 'fraud_nr' is not defined
```

I would like to know what else I need to do to be able to write to this database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep **`db_name.table_name`** enclosed in **quotes(")**

```
df.repartition("dt").write.partitionBy("dt").format("orc").saveAsTable("fraud_nr.test")
```